# Get data from foreign key relation child parent child

Tags: python, django

I have database scheme like this

[image: database]

models.py

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Attendance(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, related_name='attendance')

class Salary(models.Model):
    salary = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=0)
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, related_name='salary')
```

And I have `detailview` for salary.

views.py

```
class Salary(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'salary_detail'
    model = models.Salary
    template_name = 'system/salary_detail.html'
```

On my `template.html`

I use `salary_detail.name` to show the data.

However I also need to show `attendance` list that used to generate the salary on `salary_template.html`

How to do it?...

Comment: does each employee have only one salary object related? in that case use 'OneToOneField'. Then you can do attendance_obj.employee.salary

Comment: nope, employee will have many salary also. like salary periode `april` i need show `attendance`  from 1 april to 29 april. also for may, june, july, etc.

Comment: so salary will have a date(month) field too?

Comment: you can do `salary_obj.employee.attendance.all()` to get your employee attendance for particular salary_obj of an employee.

*this will perform join on 3 tables though*

Comment: @RamkishoreM yes, its will have date range with `date_from` and `date_to`

Comment: Umair's answer looks good. I suggest making a method in salary model called `get_attendances(self)` that'll return the attendances for that period. You can use it anywhere you want with `salary.get_attendances()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should have `to` and `from` date in `salary`, so that you can track which salary is for which dates and then filter attendance based on that something like this.

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Attendance(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, related_name='attendance')

class Salary(models.Model):
    from_date = models.DateField()
    to_date = models.DateField()
    salary = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=0)
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, related_name='salary')


employee.attendance.filter(date__gte=employee.salary.from_date, date__lte=employee.salary.to_date).values('dates')
```